# Kivy App Error- Invalid instance in App.root

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am working on building a kivy app. The below code is a simple Hello World of sorts. Press a button. The label changes from 'Hello' to 'World'

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import  Label
#from tasks import assign_task


class GetTask():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(GetTask,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.main_label = Label(text = "Hello")
        button = Button(text="Press")
        button.bind(on_press= self.update)

    def update(self):
        self.main_label.text = "World"

class MyApp(App):
   def build(self):
        return GetTask()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

The error I get when I run it is:

```
raise Exception('Invalid instance in App.root')
Exception: Invalid instance in App.root
```

I looked at this- [Kivy: Invalid instance in App.root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334362/kivy-invalid-instance-in-app-root)

I still cannot figure what I am doing wrong. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Don't you need to add widgets manually with self.add_widget(button) when they are created in Python code? Not sure that it's the reason for your issue, but right now you are just creating widget objects in memory and that's it. Nothing gets actually added to the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your GetTask inherit from? It seems to me that it doesn't inherit from anything at all. Try changing it to

```
class GetTask(Widget):
    #  The rest is like it's in your code.
```

Also have a look at my comment under the question. Not sure if it's still the issue in 1.9.1, though.

Comment: It runs now but all I get is a black screen. Could this be because of not having the self.add_widget(button)?

Comment: Nvm. got it to work. Added the `class GetTask (Widget)` and `self.add_widget(Button)`. Thanks alot mate!